# Проблема конструктора копирования С++

Tags: c++, конструктор, конструктор-копирования, оператор-присваивания

Решил ради практики реализовать урезанный класс String на С++ и столкнулся с проблемой:

Есть несколько конструкторов:

- принимающий строку **String(char*** **str)** и создающий массив char.
- копирования **String(const String & other)** создающий массив char копирующий класс String.

оператор:

- присваивания (=) **String & operator = (const String & other)** присваивающий текущему классу массив char из другого класса string.

и метод:

- **Print()** выводящий массив в виде строки в консоль.

ps. метод StrLen у меня реализован отдельно по этому написан таким образом, но работает он полностью правильно.

```
#include<iostream>

class String{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    String(char* str){
        this->str = new char[StrLen(str)+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < StrLen(str); i++){
            this->str[i] = str[i];
        }
        this->str[StrLen(str)] = '\0';
    }
    String(const String & other){
        this->str = new char[StrLen(other.str)];
        for(int i = 0; i < StrLen(other.str); i++){
            *this->str = other.str[i];
        }
    }

    String & operator = (const String & other){
        this->str = new char[StrLen(other.str)+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < StrLen(other.str); i++){
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }
        str[StrLen(str)+1] = '\0';
        return *this;
    }
}
```

и при попытке присвоить значение одного объекта другому происходит какая-то ошибка которая ломает строку.

```
int main()
{
    String str = "Lorem";
    String str1 = str; 

    str.Print();
    str1.Print();       

    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

```
Lorem
mݫ
```

Причем как я протестировал если закомментировать конструктор копирования, то все работает исправно:

```
Lorem
Lorem
```

Следовательно могу предположить что из-за одинаковых параметров программа не может определить чем именно пользоваться, но я не понимаю логику ее выбора - почему именно такой вывод и как это исправить.

Заранее огромное спасибо за ответ!!!

---

PS. понял что дело в том что программа приравнивает эти 2 операции из-за того что присваивание происходит во время объявления но логику я так и не понял

Comment: `str[StrLen(str)+1] = '\0'` - в этом месте вы считаете длину строки, которая ещё не ограничена нулем. Выход за пределы массива. Смешной момент - нулевой символ записывается в байт в котором уже нулевой символ. То есть, это оператор ничего не делает. Только создаёт неопределённое поведение.

Comment: В конструкторе копирования не копируется/проставляется терминирующий 0. И еще, вызывать Strlen в цикле - режет глаз до крови.

Comment: Почитайте про самоприсваивание. Оно вас поджидает после того как вы поправите очевидные ошибки.

Comment: Если закомментировать конструктор копирования, то программа буде два раза удалять одну строку. Что приведёт к падению. Вы его пока можете не видеть, но на выходе всё рушится.

Comment: В приведенном коде присваиваний не происходит, `String str = "Lorem"; String str1 = str;` - вызовы конструкторов. `this->str = new char[StrLen(other.str)+1];` - а тут утекает память, ранее выделенная для `str`